# Check each array value for NaN

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

I have the following array:

```
 var indexes = {
            'spear' : $('#commands_table th:has(img[src*="unit_spear"])').index(),
            'sword' : $('#commands_table th:has(img[src*="unit_sword"])').index(),
            'axe' : $('#commands_table th:has(img[src*="unit_axe"])').index(),
            'archer' : $('#commands_table th:has(img[src*="unit_archer"])').index(),
            'spy' : $('#commands_table th:has(img[src*="unit_spy"])').index(),
            'light' : $('#commands_table th:has(img[src*="unit_light"])').index(),
            'marcher' : $('#commands_table th:has(img[src*="unit_marcher"])').index(),
            'heavy' : $('#commands_table th:has(img[src*="unit_heavy"])').index(),
            'ram' : $('#commands_table th:has(img[src*="unit_ram"])').index(),
            'cata' : $('#commands_table th:has(img[src*="unit_catapult"])').index(),
            'noble' : $('#commands_table th:has(img[src*="unit_noble"])').index(),
            'knight' : $('#commands_table th:has(img[src*="unit_knight"])').index(),

            };
```

Sometimes it'll find a certain name, sometimes it won't. What I want to do is:

```
  var numberspear = $(this).closest('tr').children().eq(indexes[spear]).text();
```

Wich obviously won't work for a unit if it doens't exist. Now, i could obviously check every index seperatly, but that's not really efficient... Is there a way to check every value of my array and, if it doens't exist, remove it from the array?

Thanks

Comment: That is not an array.. it is a key/value object

Comment: try `indexes['spear']` or `indexes.spear` instead

Comment: And for god's sake, please **CACHE** `$("#commands_table th")` and use `filter()`!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could automate the filling of the object and just not add the items that are not found..

```
var items = ['spear', 'sword', 'axe', 'archer',
             'spy', 'light', 'marcher', 'heavy',
             'ram', 'cata', 'noble', 'knight'],
    indexes = {},
    headers = $('#commands_table th');

for (i=var i = 0, len = items.length; i < len; i+++){
    var item = items[i],
        index = headers.filter(':has(img[src*="unit_'+ item +'"])').index();

    if (!isNAN(index)){
        indexes[item] = index;
    }
}
```

Comment: One more question (sorry, I'm not really familliar with JS, Jquery only): var numberofspear = bevelnamen.closest('tr').childeren().eq(index).text(); Could i do this for each index (if it exists) and put in in the same (or a new) array too?

Answer (score 2):

[JsFiddle](http://jsbin.com/UxIzoPap/1/)

```
for (var key in indexes) {
   if (isNaN(indexes[key]))
      delete(indexes[key]);
}
```